# setState boolean runs twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using an animated hamburger menu button which switches to an x after being clicked. I would like to use this button to toggle the state between a home page to a menu page. I currently call the following function when this menu button is clicked:

```
menuToggleHandler = () => {
   this.setState({
       menu: !this.state.menu
})
}
```

the `this.state.menu` boolean is used to indicated whether the menu or the home page should be rendered, but when I log it in the console it says that it is being set to true immediately after it is set to false. Is there something I am missing here?

The menuToggleHandler function is being called when the parent div for an animating hamburger icon like [this](https://codepen.io/charlesscheuer/pen/gQzRmO?editors=1100) is clicked.

Comment: What event triggers `menuToggleHandler`? Put something like `console.log("Setting menu to" , !this.state.menu)` in  `menuToggleHandler ` before calling  `setState `. Maybe the handler is triggered twice?

Comment: I would say it is an issue with `menuToggleHandler` being called multiple times. We need more info on how that is being called.

Comment: Can you show the button's code? It should contain `onClick={this.menuToggleHandler}`. I've made the mistake of writing `onClick={this.menuToggleHandler()}` before and it would call the method without me clicking the button...

Comment: Can you post your code of calling menuToggleHandler?

Comment: I added more info to the post, the function is called by the div parent of the div with the class name "menu cross menu--1" on the code pen I linked.